# Command Prompt Custom Code Error

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, command, command-prompt

At my company, we have users that manually type in code into command prompt line by line. I was trying to create something that would allow them to paste one line of code, but I get an error in the code when executing.

**Here is my Code:**

```
D: & cd b2borders  & cd jar b2b & cd bin & set path=%path%;c:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre6\bin & java -jar ejecutable.jar & pause
```

**Here is my error:**

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

**Note:** When I execute the code line by line, no errors.

Please advise!!!

Thanks,
Doug F.

[image: Screenshot of Code in CMD]

[image: Screenshot of Good Code - 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are asking for a one line copy paste you could shorten your code thus:

```dos
CD /D "D:\B2Borders\Jar B2B\bin" & "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar "ejecutable.jar" & Pause
```

You may also find that an alternative using `Start` works:

```dos
Start "" /D "D:\B2Borders\Jar B2B\bin" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar "ejecutable.jar" & Pause
```

To save your end users opening a Command Prompt themselves you could even try, *(as entry into run box)*:

```dos
Cmd /K "Start "" /D "D:\B2Borders\Jar B2B\bin" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar "ejecutable.jar""
```

Comment: Thank you very much! the first line of code works! I put it into a .bat file for automation. Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `s` at `C:\Program File**s**(x86)\java\jre6\bin` in your screenshot. 
But you seemed to have typed correctly in the question.

Comment: yes - that is not the problem. Sorry about the typo. We run this everyday. How do I need to write the code in order to execute consecutively?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that as you are changing `path` in your cascaded command, the original value would be used in an attempt to locate `java.exe`, hence the error message.

The most obvious solution would be to establish a batch file to perform most of the retyping - manually entering that command would be error-prone, with the possibility of disastrous consequences if it is mistyped.

However, if you specify the entire executable name, `"c:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre6\bin\java.exe"` which would need to be within "double quotes as shown" because of the separators in the path, then the command should be executed properly. What `java` would think is yet another matter...